# How to import a class from another project in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am completely new to using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and C# and I am trying to figure out how to simply import a class that exists in another project into my console application.

I have another project named `Project1` that contains a `CreditCard.cs` file. I have tried the following for importing the `CreditCard` class:

- typing `using Project1.CreditCard`
- going to the **Solution Explorer** and then looking for "References" which I could not find, to try to include the class as an imported class.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or tell me how I might import a class in C#?

Comment: The answer to this question requires more information.  What kind of project is this (Web application, Web Site, Windows Forms App, WPF App, etc...).  Also, how exactly do you want to "import it".  Do you want to reference a dll from another project?  Or do you just want to copy the source file into your project?

Comment: I ran into a problem like this, but the issue was that one project was running NET 4.0 and the other NET 4.5. Moving both to the same version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in solution explorer, right click on your project and go to add ==> existing item, then browse to the path of your existing class.

Comment: I'd recommend referencing the other project (just in case you were finding the compiled DLL).   On the left you have lots of choices -- adding Assemblies, Projects in Solution, etc.     Choose the Projects in Solution, and add a reference to your CreditCard project.  That way, any time your CC project changes, it will be immediately reflected in your code on the other project as well.  Being new to VS-think of projects as your individual food type (hot dog, fries, etc) that are specific things- and a solution is the meal-add in any food project to make that solution work.   A wrapper of sorts.

Comment: Old thread, but for those who bump into this:  Note that (VS2019) in the dialog that comes up when you go right-click -> Add -> Existing item..., the button at the bottom of that dialog has a drop-down next to it, from which you can choose from [Add] or [Add as link].  [Add] makes a copy (snapshot) of that file and adds it to your product - if you were to make a change in one file, it would not affect the other.  [Add as link] adds a reference to the original file - no new file is created, the file stays where it is, but is used in both projects and any changes to it show in both projects.

Answer (score 14):

You right click on the project (not solution) that you want having the reference.   So click on your new project, choose Add | References --- then in the dialog, choose Solution on the left, and find your CreditCard project and add it.    It'll add the reference, and you can then use the Using in your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you say another project do you mean two projects in the same solution? if so, you have to reference the project(Project1) with the class in the other project(Project2) by doing so:

1. Left click on the project(Project2) that you want to add the reference
2. Go to Add -> Reference -> Solution
3. Target the project(Project1) you want to add and click OK

Now in your project(Project2) you can do "using Project1(name of your project)" or "using Project1.FolderName" if your class is in a folder to use that class and then:

```
CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
```